# Is it possible to use jcsg library with Processing?

Tags: java, processing, csg

Processing is a creative coding platform - language, IDE & ecosystem - maintained by the Processing community with the backing of the Processing Foundation https://processing.org. Processing Java Mode can usually benefit from code in Java libraries.

JCSG is a Java implementation of BSP based CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry) https://github.com/miho/JCSG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few hoops to jumps through coming from Processing alone, but yes, you can use any Java library in Processing. (Simply drag the library .jar on top of the saved sketch)

First you'll need to compile the [JCSG](https://github.com/miho/JCSG) .jar library along with the [VVecMath](https://github.com/miho/VVecMath) .jar library to run the sample code.

To do that you'll need [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/). You can install it from scratch or use an existing installation from your system if you've used the Android SDK / Android Studio / IntelliJ / etc.

As the [readme](https://github.com/miho/JCSG#command-line) mentions, on OSX/Linux/etc. from each library folder run:

```
bash gradlew assemble
```

On Windows run:

```
gradlew assemble
```

In my case I used the Gradle install that came with Android Studio which I had on my mac:

```
bash /Applications/IDEsAndEditors/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew assemble
```

Once you've got the .jar files compiled you can simply drop them into a saved Processing sketch. This will create a `code` folder. At this stage you can use the libraries in that sketch.

(Tip: Go to **Processing > Preferences** and enable **Code completion with Ctrl+Space** to make easier to see the available method and properties (IDEs like eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans/etc. do that by default))

I've done a quick test, however the OBJ file JCSG saves can't be parsed by Processing's built-in PShape OBJ loader.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;

PShape csgResult;

void setup(){
  size(900,900,P3D);
  // we use cube and sphere as base geometries
  CSG cube = new Cube(2).toCSG();
  CSG sphere = new Sphere(1.25).toCSG();

  // perform union, difference and intersection
  CSG cubePlusSphere = cube.union(sphere);
  CSG cubeMinusSphere = cube.difference(sphere);
  CSG cubeIntersectSphere = cube.intersect(sphere);

  // translate geometries to prevent overlapping 
  CSG union = cube.
          union(sphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(3))).
          union(cubePlusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(6))).
          union(cubeMinusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(9))).
          union(cubeIntersectSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(12)));

  // save union as stl
  try {
      FileUtil.write(
              Paths.get(sketchPath("sample.obj")),
              union.toObjString()
      );
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  //load shape into Processing
  csgResult = loadShape(sketchPath("sample.obj"));

}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5,0);
  scale(sin(frameCount * 0.1) * 100);
  if(csgResult != null){
    shape(csgResult);
  }
}
```

I did test and the vertices are there, the faces are missing through:

[image: JCSG demo vertices]

Feel try to try the STL format and a different Processing library to load,
otherwise access the vertices and draw them in Processing directly taking into account units/scales are different between JSCG and Processing:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;

CSG union;

void setup(){
  size(900,900,P3D);
  stroke(255);
  //strokeWeight(3);
  // we use cube and sphere as base geometries
  CSG cube = new Cube(2).toCSG();
  CSG sphere = new Sphere(1.25).toCSG();

  // perform union, difference and intersection
  CSG cubePlusSphere = cube.union(sphere);
  CSG cubeMinusSphere = cube.difference(sphere);
  CSG cubeIntersectSphere = cube.intersect(sphere);

  // translate geometries to prevent overlapping 
  union = cube.
          union(sphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(3))).
          union(cubePlusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(6))).
          union(cubeMinusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(9))).
          union(cubeIntersectSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(12)));

}

void drawCSG(CSG mesh,float scale){
  beginShape(POINTS);
  for(Polygon p : mesh.getPolygons()){
    for(Vertex v : p.vertices){
      vertex((float)v.pos.getX() * scale,(float)v.pos.getY() * scale,(float)v.pos.getZ() * scale);
    }
  }
  endShape();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5,0);
  rotateY(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY,0,height,PI,-PI));

  drawCSG(union,sin(frameCount * 0.01) * 100);
}
```

[image: JSCG vertex traversal]

You can download the above sketch (with pre-compiled libraries) [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/JCSGTest.zip) (and the JCSG generated documentation [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/jcsg-0.5.8-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.zip)). Be sure to go through the libraries' documentation/source code for more advanced usage.

**Update:** For efficiency you can make use of [`createShape()`](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html) to create a group of [`PShape`](https://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) objects once in setup, then simply render in `draw()` (as opposed to my previous example which traverses all polygons and vertices over and over again):

```
// the PShape reference which will contain the converted 
PShape csgResult;

void setup(){
  size(900,900,P3D);
  noStroke();
  // JCSG sample code:
    // we use cube and sphere as base geometries
    CSG cube = new Cube(2).toCSG();
    CSG sphere = new Sphere(1.25).toCSG();

    // perform union, difference and intersection
    CSG cubePlusSphere = cube.union(sphere);
    CSG cubeMinusSphere = cube.difference(sphere);
    CSG cubeIntersectSphere = cube.intersect(sphere);

    // translate geometries to prevent overlapping 
    CSG union = cube.
            union(sphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(3))).
            union(cubePlusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(6))).
            union(cubeMinusSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(9))).
            union(cubeIntersectSphere.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(12)));

    // translate merged geometry back by half the total translation to pivot around centre
    union = union.transformed(Transform.unity().translateX(-6));

  // Convert CSG to PShape -> Note: CSG units are small so we scale them up so the shapes are visible in Processing
  csgResult = CSGToPShape(union,45);
}
// re-usable function to convert a CSG mesh to a Processing PShape
PShape CSGToPShape(CSG mesh,float scale){
  // allocate a PShape group
  PShape csgResult = createShape(GROUP);
  // for each CSG polygon (Note: these can have 3,4 or more vertices)
  for(Polygon p : mesh.getPolygons()){
    // make a child PShape
    PShape polyShape = createShape();
    // begin setting vertices to it
    polyShape.beginShape();
    // for each vertex in the polygon
    for(Vertex v : p.vertices){
      // add each (scaled) polygon vertex 
      polyShape.vertex((float)v.pos.getX() * scale,(float)v.pos.getY() * scale,(float)v.pos.getZ() * scale);
    }
    // finish this polygon
    polyShape.endShape();
    //append the child PShape to the parent
    csgResult.addChild(polyShape);
  }
  return csgResult;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  lights();
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5,0);
  rotateY(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY,0,height,PI,-PI));
  shape(csgResult);
}
```

[image: JCSG rendered as PShape in Processing]

Comment: Thanks! I'm hoping to get this up & running. (However, the links to lifesine.eu are broken. You wouldn't care to update?)

Comment: @Mat Unfortunately I had some issues with hosting and I'm in the process of migrating. (I've attempted to share via other means (transfer.sh/pastebin/etc.) with no joy meanwhile). The link should be working again.

Bare in mind the link is to the libraries compiled back in 2019: you might run into issues on newer operating systems/JVM versions potentially (e.g. OSX on ARM64 architecture, etc.). If so, you need to follow the steps above (e.g setup gradle/etc.) to build from source again.

Best of luck!